# Is it possible to have options on select change from when other select changes without javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, css, ruby-on-rails-4

There are a bunch of question on this but no answers on how to do it without javascript.

If you have one form that has 2 select boxes. The second select box has different options based on what you choose for the first select box. [Here is a js example](http://output.jsbin.com/oceyo3/2). Not all users have js enabled so for these users this option would be unavailable.

Can this be achieved solely using CSS3, HTML5 and Ruby? I would show what I've got so far in trying this but I got nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You might want to wait 24 hours before asking for the user to accept your answer. I made the post then went to sleep.

Comment: I'm sorry; I will take your advice to heart.  I am a brand new member here on stackoverflow :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking is how to manipulate the DOM after it has loaded without a client-side scripting language.  This is not possible as far as I am aware; unfortunately that is not what you want to hear.

The proper solution in this case would be to have the user submit the page and generate the second selection box at that time.  You will have to rely entirely on server-side logic to handle the problem.  So basically something like:

1. Serve a page with just a single selection box
2. When the page is posted generate a similar page where the first selection is locked and display a second selection box with the possible options.
3. Continue the iteration until you have all of the required selections filled out by the user.
4. Serve the result that the user requested.

Comment: Yea I was thinking some `elsif` statements but cant think of how to know what selection is chosen. Thats the best I could think of.